# Material UI checkbox complaining to be uncontrolled

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, state, material-ui

I'm using Material UI kit for React. 
I'm making Checkboxes dynamically from states and updating them,

But I'm getting uncontrolled element error.

```
this.state = {
    services : [{service: "s1", value: false},
                {service: "s2", value: false},
                {service: "s3", value: false},
               ]
};

handleServiceCheck = (i) => {
    let services = this.state.services;
    services[i].value = !services[i].value;
    this.setState({ services: services });
};

this.state.services.map((service, i) => (
    <FormControlLabel key={i}
        control={
            <Checkbox
                checked={service.value}
                onChange={() => this.handleServiceCheck(i)}
                value={service.service}
                className={classes.checkBox}
            />
        }
        label={service.service}
    />
))
```

[image: Uncontrolled Input Element]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here.

First of all, the `checked` prop of `Checkbox` needs a boolean, but you're passing integers.

Second of all, when mutating a previous state, you shouldn't mutate it in place, you should pass a function to `setState` that takes the previous state and returns the new one.

```
handleServiceCheck = (i) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({services: 
    prevState.services.map((s, idx) => {
      return i === idx
        ? { ...s, value: !s.value }
        : s
    })
  }));
};
```

Here's a [CodeSandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/jl9wmx03n5) I created with the full fixed working version.

Answer (score 0):

`checked={service.value || false}`

or

`checked={Boolean(service.value)}`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.